# Prove that $T^2+bT+cI$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, diagonalization

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator on a real finite-dimensional inner product space $V$. And suppose that $b^2 − 4c < 0$. I want to show that the operator $T^2+bT+cI$ is invertible.

I'm wondering if the following argument is correct, especially the bolded part.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of T with corresponding eigenvector $u$. **Then $\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2 + bT + cI$ with corresponding eigenvector $u$.** Since $b^2 − 4c < 0$, we know that $\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c \ne 0$. And as $0$ isn't an eigenvalue of $T^2 + bT + cI$, it follows that that $T^2 + bT + cI$ is injective. Done.

Comment: Yes your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes. One of the fundamental facts of eigenspaces is that on the eigenspace for$~\lambda$ of $T$, any polynomial $P[T]$ in $T$ acts by the scalar $P[\lambda]$. This is very basic and trivial to prove, I'm a bit surprised why this is not taught systematically. You are using this for $P=X^2+bX+c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is wrong. At no point you used the fact that $T$ is self-adjoint. So, if your proof was correct, you would have proved taht $T^2+bT+cI$ is always invertible when $b^2-4c<0$. This is false; just take $T(x,y)=(-y,x)$, $b=0$ and $c=1$.

You proved correctly that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda^2+b\lambda+c$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2+bT+cI$. But how do you know that every eigenvalue of $T^2+bT+cI$ can be obtained by this process?

Comment: That's a great point. I see why I need to justify that, but how does the self-adjoint property give it?

Comment: Actually, do we rely on the fact that $T$ is self-adjoint to know that $\lambda$ exists? (I don't think we need to know that it actually exists for the proof to work.)

Comment: Use the fact that T is diagonalizable and that its eigenvalues are real.